# Error importing file in MongoDB Cluster error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to use mongoimport my existing .json file into the cloud cluster. But I keep getting this error

error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

I have been on the cat with mongo for an hour and they have been no help to solve my issue. I think it has to do with --file drivers.json and it finding that file.

```
./mongoimport --host muleapp-shard-00-02-bxny3.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username srusso -password MuleApp2019 --authenticationDatabase admin --db Drivers --collection driver --type json --file drivers.json
```

**error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)**

now I am getting a time out error:

**2019-11-08T14:12:38.533-0500    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: muleapp-shard-00-02-bxny3.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp 3.229.7.228:27017: i/o timeout**

Comment: I have the same error, did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error could be due to long option password being provided using `-` rather than `--`. So the option could be provided as either of `--password MuleApp2019` or `-p MuleApp2019`.

Comment: noticed that one after, this utimately came down to a network security issue. fml. lol.